# mongoose — check if ObjectId exists in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, contains

Following is an example model:

```
UserModel == {
    name: String,
    friends: [ObjectId],
}
```

`friends` corresponds to a list of `id` of objects of some other model for example `AboutModel`.

```
AboutModel == {
    name: String,
}

User.findOne({name: 'Alpha'}, function(error, user){
    About.find({}, function(error, abouts){ // consider abouts are all unique in this case
        var doStuff = function(index){
            if (!(about.id in user.friends)){
                user.friends.push(about.id);
                about.save();
            }
            if (index + 1 < abouts.length){
                doStuff(index + 1)
            }
        }
        doStuff(0) // recursively...
    })
})
```

In this case, the condition 'about.id in user.friends` seems to be always false. How? Is this to do with the type of ObjectId or the way it is saved?

Note: `ObjectId` is short for `Schema.ObjectId`; I don't know if that's an issue in itself.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If `about.id` is a string representation of an ObjectID and `user.friends` is an array of ObjectIDs, you can check if `about.id` is in the array using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var isInArray = user.friends.some(function (friend) {
    return friend.equals(about.id);
});
```

The `some` call will iterate over the `user.friends` array, calling `equals` on each one to see if it matches `about.id` and stop as soon as it finds a match.  If it finds a match it returns `true`, otherwise `false`.

You can't use something simpler like `indexOf` because you want to compare the ObjectIDs by value, not by reference.

Comment: So basically this is the same as `==` in a `forEach`?

Comment: TypeError: Object 5274958d4ddfd6341858b2f7 has no method 'equals'.

Comment: what if the array is populated?

Comment: the `arrayLikeProperty.some(document => document.equals(objectId))` works even if the property is populated! thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

I use lo-dash and do something like that :

```
var id_to_found = '...';
var index = _.find(array, function(ch) {
     return ch == id_to_found ;
});
if ( index!=undefined ) {
     // CHILD_ALREADY_EXISTS
} else {
     // OK NOT PRESENTS
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought it was a translation issue or something.

Answer (score -3):

I believe this is a javascript question rather than a Node.js/Mongoose question - so it really doesn't belong in the way it is currently now.

Also, the issue with `about.id in user.friends` is that the object pointed to by `about.id` and objects in `user.friends` are different; and I believe `in` checks for the equality of the object.

Anyway, the answer is available on stack overflow to check where an element exists in an array —

```
user.friends.indexOf(about.id) > -1
```

Comment: Doesn't work with ObjectIds, that was why they asked the question

Comment: *I* asked this question.

Comment: Ah yes apologies for that!

Comment: That will only work if both your fields are of type string, which from the question they aren't